# .tar vs .tgz...what is the difference?

Tags: command-line, tar

So I was just archiving an assignment for email submission, and was asked by the instructor to do so using the tar command and create a .tgz file, which I did with the following command line script:

```
tar -cvf filename.tgz {main.cpp other filenames here}
```

No problems on the archive or anything, but when I went to email the file, gmail prevented me saying that my file contained an executable (I'm assuming main.cpp?), and that this was not allowed for security reasons.

So, I ran the same script, but this time created a .tar file instead, like so:

```
tar -cvf filename.tar {main.cpp filenames here}
```

Again, archives just fine, but now gmail is fine with me emailing the archive. So what is the difference? I've only really used tar for this purpose, so I'm not really familiar with what the different extensions are utilized for. Obviously, I've figured out a way to get the functionality I need, but like all tinkerers, I'm curious.

What say you?

Comment: Hm, after reading [this](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en), it seems gmail supports .tgz, but in your case .tgz file was uncompressed. I suppose gmail tried to gunzip it, failed and decided to play safe and block the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Absolutely no difference.  A filename is just a filename.  *Usually*, when you use the `tgz` form, it's to indicate that you've gzipped the tar file (either as a second step or using the `z` flag):

```
tar zcvf filename.tgz {filenames}
```

or

```
tar cvf filename {filenames}
gzip -S .tgz filename
```

`.tar`, on the other hand, normally means "this is an *uncompressed* tar file":

```
tar cvf filename.tar {filenames}
```

Most modern tar implementations also support the `j` flag to use `bzip2` compression, so you might also use:

```
tar jcvf filename.tar.bz2 {filenames}
```

Comment: To be clearer here, in Linux file extensions have zero impact at the operating system level. Extensions are used only at the application level (like with vim) or by human conventions. Using .tar technically has no impact at the OS level, but it can be confusing for people trying to work with the file.

Comment: +1 @Swiss.  It's why [`file(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/file/) exists.

Comment: Also, I would advise against using bzip. It results in slightly smaller archives (~10%), but takes 10x to 100x as long to run. The small space savings are not worth the time trade off.

Comment: @Carl Norum: Cool, any idea why gmail would block one and not the other if the files within are the same?

Comment: 10% can be a big deal if you have a big archive.  YMMV.

Comment: I don't know anything about gmail, sorry.

Comment: @Carl Norum: Unfortunately, if you have a big archive of 1+ GiB, bzip2 will probably take multiple DAYS to finish running. It's absolutely not worth the extra time.

Comment: @wvm2008 gmail probably has very basic file extension filtering that does not verify that the actual contents of the file match the extension. Geocities used to have the same thing. As to why you would want to filter .tar.gz files: it's actually possible to create a tar.gz file that is only a few KiB in size that expands to many exabytes in size. That will kill any computer that tries to extract it.

Comment: @Swiss sounds reasonable, thanks for the insight

Comment: @Swiss also known as a [zip bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb)